# "Something like that"

Tags: phrases

My English teacher ripped our heads off if we tried to explain something that we couldn't really describe by adding "something like that".

Sample: "This is a board game or something like that".

What are the better alternatives? "Something similar"?

Comment: Your teacher could answer this better than EL&U

Comment: My last English lesson was 9 years ago so I can't ask anymore :)

Comment: As the other have suggested, there is nothing idiomatically wrong with "something like that", though "something similar" might be more common in a sentence like yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Something similar" is okay, and perhaps slightly better, but I don't think the phrasing was what made your teacher mad.  Using "or something similar" does not explain something you couldn't really translate; it just is noise, and does not add anything.  Leave it off.

Comment: This is pretty much it. I think your teacher is trying to get you to put more thought into your explanations.

Comment: @WarrenFaith: You're not the only one :) Many of my teachers hated that phrase, as well. Even my physics teacher would not have his students reply *any* question whatsoever using that phrase. For instance, one could hear the following exchange: "Are you in [...]'s class?" "Something like that, sir." *Absolument ridicule*. Yes, avoid it like the plague!